# Publish Lambda With .Net Standard 2.0

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, visual-studio-2017

I am using C# to create lambda functions and I want to update my lambda functions to use .NET Standard 2.0. When I try to publish using the AWS toolkit in visual studio 2017 I am unable to set the Framework to netcoreapp2.0. I tried setting the framework in aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json, but it didn't change it when I tried to publish (by right clicking on the project).

I get the following error (Since I am referencing .NET Standard 2.0 libraries): Assets file 'xxxxxxxx' doesn't have a target for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'. Ensure you have included 'netcoreapp1.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/

I updated the TargetFramework in the .csproj file to netcoreapp2.0 as well

How can I update the Framework to netcoreapp to v2.0 when publishing in Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: Does AWS even support 2.0 yet?

Comment: @DavidG - no, 1.1.0 at max.  From [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/lambda-cli-publish.html) - _You must have Visual Studio 2015 Update 3_ - no 2017 support.

Answer (score 1):

Too late but now, You can now develop your AWS Lambda function code in C# using the .NET Core 2.0.

[Reference - AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/01/aws-lambda-supports-c-sharp-dot-net-core-2-0/)

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda only supports .NET Core 1.0. Your target framework must be set there in order to publish it as a Lambda. This means you will have to downgrade all your NuGet Packages to 1.0.x. It might be worth rebuilding the app and copying the code over from scratch.